# Поддержка аппаратного RAID 10 при установке Linux

Tags: raid, linux

Доброго времени суток!

Надо поставить linux (дистрибутив по большому счету не важен, но хотелось бы что-то серверное) на аппаратный RAID 10 из четырех винтов по 2Тб. Хочется сделать из машинки NAS. Столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой - установщик не видит созданный RAID. В интернетах пишут по этой проблеме достаточно много, но все предложенные пути решение изобилуют всякого рода костылями.

Собственно вопрос - есть ли дистрибутив, который без шаманства увидит аппаратный RAID (пробовал Ubuntu-server, Fedora, freeNAS, openfiler - последние два как раз сборочки для организации NAS'a)? И если нет, то может решить проблему пересборка ядра с подсовыванием драйверов контроллера?

Ситуация усугубляется еще и тем, что машинка дешевая и контроллер там, думаю, так себе.
Или попытаться сделать массив программными средствами (хотя аппаратные больше мне по душе)?

**UPD:** Спасибо за участие. Проблема решилась выставлением в BIOS'е режима ACHI :)

Comment: 1. Пробуй SUSE, у них установщик очень располатает к этому:) 2. А если серьезно - какой raid контроллер в машине? 3. По поводу програмного решения - почему бы и нет. Какого рода данные собираешься хранить?

Comment: Бэкапы серверов, файлопомойку сделать, логи всякие. Короче весь хлам, который в файловом виде в сети есть :)  А у SUSE есть возможность ставиться без гуи, т.е. чтоб только терминал был? А то чет нет у меня доверия ко всяким гномам, кедам и иже с ними)  А контроллер ваще какой-то noname

Answer (score 2):

У меня стоит CentOS видит все RAID на железке.

Comment: спасибо, будем смотреть)

Answer (score 2):

Если контроллер Intel, то он только притворяется аппаратным, а на деле он программный. У нас такая же проблема была, оказалось, что работать с ним из коробки умеют centos и opensuse. Начальник поставил два центоса, а я поставил opensuse. На сусе пару раз массив падал в readonly, в интернете написано как исправить через mdadm, больше проблем не было.

Comment: спасибо. попробую)